# what does "present company included" mean

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

There is failure to see the forest for the trees; the silver lining in the cloud, may cause small-minded men to reject women; present company excluded/included,  because of their other than acceptable size

Comment: This sentence as given does not seem to make good sense. I suspect errors in posting it here, or possibly in the source. Where did this come from please, and can additional context be provided?

Answer (score 1):

See [this thread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/204452/when-you-are-going-to-make-clear-that-who-you-were-just-talking-about-was-someon/204454#204454) and [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/215313/modern-substitutes-for-saving-your-presence-reverence) for "present company excepted" the older and more common phrase. "Present company included" is intended to be a deliberate reversal of that phrase, it means "the remark **does** apply to those her in this conversation".

However, the sentence in the question is not clear enough to say how the phrase was intended **in that sentence**.